# List all built-in functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, reflection, built-in

Is there a way in js to list all the builtin functions and some info on their parameterlists? I couldn't really find anything about reflection to do this sort of thing

edit:
The functions such as Math.sin are actually the ones I want to list, actually all built-in functions.

Comment: What is the point of doing this? How would you use the list?

Comment: Why / Where you want this ? Please explain something more

Comment: What do you mean by built-in functions? Functions defined in the specification for the global object? Methods of built-in objects (defined by the specification)? Functions of host objects common to browsers? Functions of the DOM?

Comment: Built-in where? In the browsers? In the language?

Comment: Just open the browsers inspector tool and start browsing the hierarchy of objects/methods

Comment: They are for use in a lisp project. And all functions is as they are specified in the standard, global object, object object, function object etc.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this, maybe?

```
for( var x in window) {
    if( window[x] instanceof Function) console.log(x);
}
```

This will list all native functions in the console (excluding one in native objects, such as `Math.sin()`).

Comment: Thank you, this brings me a little closer, I've changed it to this:

for(var x in window)
{
 if(typeof eval('window.' + x) == 'function')
 {
  console.log(eval('window.' + x));
 }
}

However, functions such as Math.sin etc are exactly the ones I want to list

Comment: @Frawr: Any reason you use `eval`? Why not `typeof window[x] === 'function'` and `console.log(window[x])`?

Comment: This does not list `XMLHttpRequest`. Is there a way to get this also?

Comment: @heinob Not really. A lot of things will be made non-Enumerable, so they won't show up in a loop like this. This might even be done on purpose with all native stuff, so that a `for..in` could be "useful" as in "iterate through all user-defined global variables" - ideally, this would be empty.

Comment: Is there a nodejs version of this little script?

Answer (score 1):

Just do console.log(window). Now open your browser and go to console. You will find all the built-in functions of the Javascript like Math.sin and XMLHttpReuest. It will show the complete information about arguments, length, caller and everything about that function.[image]