# Javascript default functions?

Tags: c#, javascript

In Javascript, like `setInterval(draw,20)` you don't include anything like in C#. You can just use the function. The function is on the `Windows` object of the browser.

1. Can the following objects and its functions be called without any pre-definitions?

   ```
   Window
   Navigator
   Screen
   History
   Location
   ```
2. Does JavaScript has any built-in functions?

Comment: The first question isn't clear. The second makes no sense.

Comment: C# and Javascript look mildly similar, but are not similar at all in practice. Sorry.

Comment: I've added the `C#` tag in case someone with both C# and Javascript skills can help here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693965/list-all-built-in-functions-in-javascript

Comment: What objects are available depend on what is provided by what is hosting your JavaScript.  While in a browser you can depend on the Window object, in another host such as Node.js, the Window won't exist.  Built-in functions and what not also depend on what version of JavaScript/ECMAScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javscript, there are certain things which are part of the language and will also be there.  Native objects, like `Array()`, `String()` and `Number()`.  (Not a complete list).  These need no prefix in front of them, because there are none.

In addition, when **running on the browser** the host environment provides a global variable called `window` that is the same as the anonymous Javascript `global` that everything runs in.  Methods of the `window` object include things like `alert()` and `setTimeout()`

Alert can be called with `window.alert()` or more often by just `alert()` itself.  (Some people consider calling `window.alert()` best practice to a) show you are calling the global function and b) protect you from any local variables named `alert`.)

Clarification:

The Javascript engine keeps a global variable with no name and not normally accessible.  When not running in struct mode, undeclared variables are created as properties in this global object, all global functions are put in the global object and `this` normally called functions points to the global object.

When running in the browser, `window` is the global object.

Comment: *the host environment provides a global variable called window that is the same as the anonymous Javascript global that everything runs in* - I don't know why, but this bothers me.

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- I couldn't figure out a better way to phrase it... but I'll try.

Comment: Maybe that's what's the problem. If you have no scope, you're in `window`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3dy8S/ `window` is default to a more specific scope (in browser clients). The thing is, there's a base scope, and `window` in browsers is that scope.

Comment: @JaredFarrish "If you have no scope you are in the window" is only true if you are running Javascript **in the browser.**  If you are running it anywhere else, you are in the Javascript unnamed `global object.`

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "in browser clients". I have no node.js experience, or other (?) library executables. In a browser, it's `window`.

Comment: Try coding things in Microsoft's `jscript` using `wscript` or `cscript` -- you learn REAL FAST what assumptions you can't make anymore.  I'd say about 1/4 of my coding is done there.

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- Neither is what runs in the Microsoft browser, or in Chrome.  `Javascript` is an owned trademark by ... I think Mozilla has it now.  However, `jscript` is a conforming ECMAScript standard which makes it as much of what we call Javascript as everything else.

Comment: Whatever, the trademark is beside the point.

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- JScript is a fully compliant version of **ECMA-262 3rd edition** which makes it Javascript in all but name.  l/p on the topic.

Comment: I'm still talking about browsers; you obviously can represent the non-browser environment better than I (trademark or no trademark). When most people bring it up, Javascript is in a browser environment, as I imagine the OP meant. It's a crucial yet non-demarcated difference. But it wasn't a great question to begin with, so...

Comment: And, you know, ECMA 3 was way back in a day called *1999*. That's like saying I'm driving a Mustang, but that Mustang was a circa 1974 Mustang II. It's not the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16476/discussion-between-jeremy-j-starcher-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: No. Let's not. It's really not worth the effort, since I think you're waaayyy more into than me. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'd say *"the host environment provides a global variable called window"* is pretty accurate. ECMAScript doesn't require that the variable object of the global lexical environment be exposed. That's an "add-on" by the host.

Comment: @graystateiscoming - Funny then that the rest of it was the part I couldn't quite get, but hey, I'm sure I'm learning here.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes to both :)

Assuming you're interested in client side javascript (running on a webpage within a browser), I strongly suggest you follow the tutorials on [code academy](http://www.codecademy.com/), which will answer your questions by teaching you how Javascript works, how you interact with the browser, and what the functions and methods the browser makes available to you.

Once you've finished the tutorial, things should be a lot clearer, and since you already know C# it shouldn't take too long to adjust.

Comment: Oh lord, please refrain from w3schools links on SO, see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript and http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/ instead.

Comment: Good gravy, I had no idea. It's been many, many years since I read the w3schools tutorial. Edited to point at code academy instead

Comment: Well, I get an error when I try that link.

Comment: Ok, that link works now. `:)`

Comment: Lovely copy/paste error. Fixed.